# Add empty cells if two columns do not match in Excel

Tags: excel, rows

is there a way to accomplish edit as seen in the included picture without using a macro?

Number of cells in column C with each category can be equal or lesser than in column A.
When a number of cells with categories in column C is lesser then i want to add empty cells for all data columns. I would appreciate any tips.
[image]

Comment: column A & C is different.. Then column b is the gap.. OK. But Column C n D is different too.. and have no gap.. is it not OK?

Comment: Column A is there to show how many categories there are and how many there is maximum number of cells of each category.  Columns C to F are the data i want to edit. Columns H to K is the output i want to have. Columns H should look the same as Column A but what is different is number of empty cells in data Columns I to K that depends on Column C

Comment: how does your original data looks like?

Comment: Original Data are in Columns C to F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in I2, and drag till K31 :

```
=IF(COUNTIF($H$2:$H2,$H2)<=COUNTIF($C:$C,$H2),INDEX(D:D,MATCH($H2,$C:$C,0)+COUNTIF($H$2:$H2,$H2)-1),"")
```

Idea/ref : use index match to load the values in source column, based on the count of "Catagories X" in column H. If it is more than the count of "Catagories X" in column C, display a blank.

Please share if it works/not. ( :

Comment: So far this looks to work perfectly. Thank you a lot. :))